# i keep getting token rightparen expected error when i try to use if statement on power query editor for powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

this is my code

```
-- if([Discount Band]="None",0,if([Discount Band]="Low",0.01,if([Discount Band]="Medium",0.05,0.1)))
```

Screenshot of my work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, for M/Power Query it is 'if then else' not comma separated, like DAX/Excel. A good example is [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/08/27/the-if-function-in-power-query/)

```
 if([Discount Band]="None",0,if([Discount Band]="Low",0.01,if([Discount Band]="Medium",0.05,0.1)))
```

this should be

```
if [Discount Band]= "None" then 0 else 
  if [Discount Band]= "Low" then 0.01 else 
    if [Discount Band]= "Medium" then 0.05 else 0.1
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error, the if functions in M uses the following format: If...Then...Else

```
if [Discount Band]="None"
    then 0
    else if [Discount Band]="Low"
        then 0.01
        else if [Discount Band]="Medium"
            then 0.05
            else 0.1
```

Comment: An answer that just consists of code doesn't help the reader understand.